How to Show that a σ-algebra Containing Singletons is the Power Set?
Let $X$ be a countable set. A family $\mathcal{G} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$ of subsets of $X$ is said to separate points in $X$ if for all $x, y \in X$ with $x \neq y$, there exists $G \in \mathcal{G}$ such that $G$ contains only one of $x$ and $y$, i.e., $G \setminus {x, y}$ is either ${x}$ or ${y}$.
I have a σ-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ on $X$ that contains all singletons ${x}$ for $x \in X$. I want to prove that $\mathcal{A} = \mathcal{P}(X)$.
How can I approach this proof? What steps should I follow to demonstrate that $\mathcal{A}$ indeed includes all subsets of $X$?.
I've tried to use cardinality, but this does not seem to prove it very well.
Thank you for your help!

$X$ is countable and $\sigma$-algebras are closed under countable unions.

But how does this help? How do i show i generate all subsets with the singletons?

@Mathias Do you know that every subset of a countable set is countable?

@Mathias a countable set is a countable union of singletons

I was about to write that it's false, but then I saw the condition that $X$ is countable. This can be done in the good ol' set theoretic way. You want to prove $\mathcal{A}=\mathcal{P}(x)$, so you must prove $\mathcal{A}\subseteq\mathcal{P}(X)$ and $\mathcal{P}(X)\subseteq\mathcal{A}$. The first inclusion is trivial from the definition of a sigma-algebra. $\mathcal{A}$ is defined to be a collection of subsets of $X$, so it's elements are also in $\mathcal{P}(X)$. Now let's prove the 2nd one. We do so by taking an arbitrary element of $\mathcal{P}(X)$ and prove it to be in $\mathcal{A}$. Let's call this element $x$. Since $X$ is countable, and $x$ is known to be a subset of $X$, then $x$ is at most countable (it can also just be finite). We know the union $\bigcup_{u\in x}\{u\}=x$ is a union of singletons, and is countable, so from our assumption, it's a countable union of elements of the $\Sigma$-algebra, and by the defining properties of $\Sigma$-algebra, the union is in $\mathcal{A}$ as well. Thus we proved the two-directuonal inclusion that means it's an equality.
